# MySQL query on sum() while returning detail of a particular row

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I've got a table

```
id pos status price
1 US 0 0 
1 UK 1 0
1 HK 2 100
2 HK 0 0
2 UK 1 200
...
```

and I want to show the sum(price) of each id while showing the pos of the record where status=0

i.e.

```
id pos sum(price)
1 US 100
2 HK 200
...
```

Any way to do it without using temp table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation with a conditional expression for `pos`:

```
select id, max(case when status = 0 then pos end) as pos_0, sum(price)
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `exists` like below

```
select id,pos,sum(price)
from table_name t1
where exists ( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.status=0)
group by id,pos
```

Comment: Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 't1'